# Matlab optimization toolbox and knapsack

Tags: matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm, knapsack-problem

I have a few questions regarding this tool.Also with this tool I am using the GA from the dropdown list. Particularly for solving a 0-1 knapsack. First can number of items,weights, and values be defined in the toolbox or must that be defined in the fitness function beforehand? Second I know that with knapsack the output is 0 or 1 in there a way to define this in the toolbox or must that also be set in the fitness function code beforehand?One of the codes I have seen was like this:

y = (25*x(1)+20*x(2)+15*x(3)+40*x(4)+50*x(5));

with this the number of items is included in the function along with values.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions, which will help people give you better answers. In particular, add the code of what you've already tried.

Comment: This is more of a in general question before I start coding, however one of the codes I have seen was like this:y = (25*x(1)+20*x(2)+15*x(3)+40*x(4)+50*x(5));     Seems like number of items was already included though